# How to make the same calculation for multiple new columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following dataframes:

df1:

```
a        b    
'a'      'aaaaa'
'bb'     'bbbb'
'ccc'    'ccc'
'dddd'   'dd'
'eeeee'  'e'
```

df2:

```
c       d    
'aaa'   'a'
'bbb'   'bb'
'ccc'   'ccc'
'ddd'   'dddd'
'eee'   'eeeee'
```

I want to make the same calculation for all columns, which yields a new column.

Assume the calculation is `lambda x,y: len(x)+len(y)`

Then the result df would be:

```
ac     bd    
4      6
5      6
6      6
7      6
8      6
```

What I care about is avoiding the for loop over all the columns/elements.
**How can I do the same calculation over all relevant columns `column_list1`, `column_list2`?**

---

Performed major edit to give better non trivial example (I hope)

Comment: `df1.values + df2.values`? I guess you need other example.

Comment: @QuangHoang editted, I hope this is comlpicated enough

Comment: Can't think of a simpler way than your original solution, except that you don't concat every time. Put everything into one array `results` and `pd.concat(results, axis=1)` outside of `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `applymap`

```
c = df1.columns + df2.columns
d1 = df1.set_axis(c, axis=1, inplace=False)
d2 = df2.set_axis(c, axis=1, inplace=False)

d1.applymap(len) + d2.applymap(len)

   ac  bd
0   4   6
1   5   6
2   6   6
3   7   6
4   8   6
```

---

#### `stack` and `str.len`

```
c = df1.columns + df2.columns
d1 = df1.set_axis(c, axis=1, inplace=False)
d2 = df2.set_axis(c, axis=1, inplace=False)

(d1.stack().str.len() + d2.stack().str.len()).unstack()
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because `applymap` seems like the most general case which is also the most readable to by inexperienced eye. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
df1[:]=df1.values+df2.values
df1
Out[65]: 
       a     b
0  110.0  11.0
1  220.0  22.0
2  330.0  33.0
3  440.0  44.0
4  550.0  55.0
```

---

Just assign the `columns` `df1` back to `df2`

```
df2.columns=df1.columns
df1+df2
```

---

Update

```
df2.columns=df1.columns
(df1+df2).apply(lambda x : x.str.len(),1)
Out[81]: 
   a  b
0  4  6
1  5  6
2  6  6
3  7  6
4  8  6
```

Comment: Let me edit the question... Elements can be strings, and built in operations won't work

Comment: Edited with a very different example

Comment: Can you explain please? What is `(df1+df2)`? Why the `,1` after .len()?

Comment: @Gulzar df1 + df2 will do the columns wise and row wise sum base on the index , axis=1 mean we apply the function over the columns .

Comment: @Gulzar in pandas ,. the columns and index is the hidden key when to do the calculation , which only if the columns and index match , the value will be added